# How to develop a hybrid Fiori application and launch it on Fiori custom client?

Tags: sapui5, hybrid, sap-fiori

I develop SAPUI5 and Fiori applications by SAP WEBIDE and deploy them on SAP Getway server, which is using as the applications web server. After deploying, we expose the application to the user by Fiori Launchpad (Fiori Client). 
We do not have SAP Cloud platform or SMP. 
I asked to develop a hybrid Fiori application that uses device capabilities (like barcode, camera, etc). I used node JS CLI for adding Cordova plugins to SAPUI5 and wrapping the application for getting APK. How can I develop a hybrid application, which can be reached by Fiori launchpad / Fiori client (Not standalone APK)?

Answer (score 0):

If you were build your application with sap/m/* libraries, you can use existing SAP Fiori Client ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sap.fiori.client&hl=en) / [IOS](https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/sap-fiori-client/id824997258?l=en)) for barcode scanning, camera, etc. Also you can use it for UI5 applications.

If you create own app with SAP Fiori Client SDK, you need extra license for it.

It is theoretically possible to run Fiori app in Cordova, but I think you need a lot of custom work. I prefer use SAP Fiori Client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I am Ok with Developing a Fiori hybrid application and deploying it on SAP Fiori client. I do not know how to combine SAP Fiori Client plugin for using device ability like a camera and barcode. Take your consideration that we do not have SMP our SAP mobile cloud platform.  Any cookbook guide or sample will be appreciated.

Comment: You can check [SAPUI5 API reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner) for barcode functionality.